# Laravel Eloquent Accessor Strange Issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
Laravel Version: 5.6.39
PHP Version: 7.1.19
Database Driver & Version: mysql 5.6.43
```

Description:

When I chain where and orWhere in a model accessor to count related model , I get wrong result and here is my query. the count is returned strange result without filtering by the calling event id,

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';
    public function registrations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Components\Event\Models\Registration','event_id','id');
    }

    public function getSeatsBookedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->registrations()          
            ->where('reg_status','=','Confirmed')
            ->orWhere('reg_status','=','Reserved')
            ->count();
    }
}
```

**Steps To Reproduce:**

the following queries return me the expected results, however In my knowledge the first query should return the same result if i am not wrong, so i think this is a potential bug.

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function getSeatsBookedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->registrations()          
             ->whereIn('reg_status', ['Confirmed', 'Reserved'])
            ->count();
    }

}


class Event extends Model
{
    public function getSeatsBookedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->registrations()          
          ->where(function($query){
                $query->where('reg_status','Confirmed')
                    ->orWhere('reg_status','Reserved');
           })
            ->count();
    }

}
```

and here is the query dump,

here is the query when I donot explicit group it.

```
"select count(*) as aggregate from events_registration where (events_registration.event_id = ? and events_registration.event_id is not null and reg_status = ? or reg_status = ?) and events_registration.deleted_at is null "
```

and here is the query when i group it explicitly,

```
select count(*) as aggregate from events_registration where events_registration.event_id = ? and events_registration.event_id is not null and (reg_status = ? or reg_status = ?) and events_registration.deleted_at is null
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because you're chaining `where()` and `orWhere()`. What you don't see behind the scenes is a `where event_id = :event_id` applying to your query. You end up with a query that looks something like this:

```sql
select * from registrations where event_id = :event_id and reg_status = 'Confirmed' or reg_status = 'Reserved'
```

In normal SQL you'd want to put the last 2 conditions in parentheses. For Eloquent, you'd need to do something like this:

```php
return $this->registrations()->where(function ($query) {
   $query->where('reg_status', 'Confirmed')
      ->orWhere('reg_status', 'Reserved');
});
```

You can chain the `toSql()` method on these chains to see the difference. Note, that in this case, I believe `whereIn()` is the semantically correct thing to do.

Eloquent can handle this for you, though; scroll down to "Counting Related Models" in the [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) part of the Eloquent Relationships docs:

```php
$posts = App\Event::withCount([
    'registrations as seats_booked_count' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('reg_status','Confirmed')
                ->orWhere('reg_status','Reserved');
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: You are correct, if i explicitly group the where statement, the query works fine or using `whereIn` also solves the problem, 
in my aspect the framework must handle this by grouping my statement separate or at-least mention this in the document as a warning, isnot it? .
I opened an issue in github about this.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27796#issuecomment-470013819

Comment: How is the framework supposed to determine if/how you want to group them? `where()->orWhere()` won't put anything in parens, but you want `where()->where()->orWhere()` to put them in parens? I don't see an easy solution here. If the idea is "check to see how many where methods are chained" - as you can see in the above example, the developer didn't write the first `where()`.

Comment: look at my question, i update it with query dump in both case, when group it my self and not group it,